# Create Session cookies and posting in final page

Tags: php, forms, session, post, cookies

I have a form "A" where visitors enter color of outfit chosen, then form "B" where they enter other infos like measurements and other specifications.
Now, instead of posting the two forms separately, i want after they fill and submit form A, a page (verNote.php) creates a session cookie to store the entry, and proceeds to the form B.

After filling form B, when posting infos on form B, it should call infos from form A stored via session cookies and add to the inputs to POST.

When i use the code below, i dont get the inputs from form A posted on submit of the final page.

Below is my (verNote.php)

```
<?php

ini_set('session.save_path', 'tmp');
session_start();
$chosenColour = $_POST['chosenColour'];
$chosenMatch = $_POST['chosenMatch'];
$ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
$_SESSION['chosenColour'] = $chosenColour;
$_SESSION['chosenMatch'] = $chosenMatch;
setcookie("chosenColour", $chosenColour, time()+3600);
setcookie("chosenMatch", $chosenMatch, time()+3600);
header("Location: formB.php");

?>
```

Form A has just 2 entries, while B has 4 entries, and they post perfectly if i decide to post them independently. But i want both entries in both A and B to be submitted once.

Sorry, this is best info i can make available.
will appreciate assistance on how to effectively achieve this.
Ruse!

Comment: Please include you form code too...

Comment: ok..do these forms exist on same page..?

Comment: no, formA.php and formB.php, both on same folder tho.

Comment: Just curious..why are are you using two forms on a same page..?

Comment: You dont seem to get me, i am NOT using two forms on same page. Read my post carefully. i have 2 different pages both with one form each.

Comment: You can `POST` the values of form A onto form B page and pass it as `hidden` input type data along form B..and finally you can get all data on your final page (verNote.php)...

Comment: How? Mind writing me a simple line to show me your point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it goes:

On `A.php`

```
<form action="B.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="sex">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

On `B.php`

```
<form action="verNote.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="color">
    <input type="text" name="measure">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $_POST['name'] ?>" >
    <input type="hidden" name="sex" value="<?php echo $_POST['sex'] ?>" >
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

On `verNote.php` simply get all the values using `POST`.
Try somthing like this...it will work...

Your `verNote.php` will be something like this..

```
<?php
echo $_POST['name'];
echo '<br>';
echo $_POST['sex'];
echo '<br>';
echo $_POST['color'];
echo '<br>';
echo $_POST['measure'];
```

I have completely tested this code...And I am to receive 4 values at the end...
If it doesn't work, might be something else in your code then...

Comment: Didnt work. With this, i only got entries of form B submitted.